# How to store object data from an asynchronous task?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a controller method that gets a data from an API.

The `LeaveBalanceAsync` is called by an AJAX when my page loads.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> LeaveBalanceAsync(int empnum)
        {


            return await APICallAsync(empnum);



        }
        private async Task<IActionResult> APICallAsync(int emp)
        {
            //Fetch the JSON string from URL.
            LeaveModel leave = new LeaveModel();
            string apiUrl = $"http://myapi/{emp}";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(apiUrl);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                APIResponse<LeaveModel> apiResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<APIResponse<LeaveModel>>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
                leave = apiResponse.Data;
                userLeave = leave;
            }

            //Return the Deserialized JSON object.
            return Json(leave);

        }
```

I would like to store the data that I got from that method to an object like this (as you can see above I tried to pass it into the `userLeave` model/object but after the `LeaveBalanceAsync` is done executing,the data that was captured and stored into `userLeave` is also gone)

```
  public LeaveModel userLeave = new LeaveModel();
```

Or is there any possible ways I can do this using another method to store it into that object?

Comment: Why are you returning an `IActionResult` if you want a `LeaveModel` in `LeaveBalanceAsync`?

Comment: The reason this is happening is because each request gets a new instance of your controller.  Why do you want to store the value?  If its caching, you could look into IMemoryCache

Comment: Could you pls share your scenario? Why you want to store the data to userLeave? Have you tried Session or database to store?